# How can I use the Cyclic repetition option in the 'From Workspace' Simulink block to include Matlab data in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Assume I have an arbitrary nx1 array in the Matlab workspace. How can I import this array as a source into Simulink and use cyclic repetition to extend the data beyond its final value?

I know the ‘From Workspace’ block in Simulink, and saw that it has an option called ‘Cyclic repetition’. However if I want to use my nx1 array I get the error message “Invalid variable specified as workspace input”.

Comment: If the answer below solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

To use the `From workspace` block your Matlab data must be in a specific format. E.g. for a sine wave signal you need to use a `struct` of the following format:

```
y.signals.values=sin(0:0.01:10*pi)';
y.signals.dimensions=1;
y.time = [ ];
```

Then in the `From Workspace` block make sure you set the correct variable for data, uncheck *Interpolate data* and set *Cyclic repetition* like this

[image: Required settings in the From Workspace block]

Now you can verify that the correct data was imported from the workspace by simply feeding it through to a scope:

[image: Verify imported data using simple model]

The resulting output looks like this and confirms that the `From Workspace` block worked as intended as it repeats the original data until 10000s:

[image: Output until 10000 seconds]

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, so that other users can find it easier.

Comment: Note that you may need to be careful about what happens at the end point of your data.  With this example, at the repetition time, you will get sin(10*pi) followed by sin(0), which may not be exactly what you want.  For this specific example you might want to also use `y.signals.values(end) = [];` to remove the end point and hence make the sine wave smooth at the repetition time rather than include the replication of data.  (This may or may not be an issue with real data, but worth noting.)